# Hierarchical Agglomerative clustering in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on a clustering problem and it has to be scalable for a lot of data. I would like to try hierarchical clustering in Spark and compare my results with other methods.

I have done some research on the web about using hierarchical clustering with Spark but haven't found any promising information.

If anyone has some insight about it, I would be very grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### The Bisecting Kmeans Approach

Seems to do a decent job, and runs quite fast in terms of performance. Here is a sample code I wrote for utilizing the Bisecting-Kmeans algorithm in Spark (scala) to get cluster centers from the Iris Data Set (which many people are familiar with). Note: (I use Spark-Notebook for most of my Spark work, it is very similar to Jupyter Notebooks). I bring this up because you will need to create a Spark SQLContext for this example to work, which may differ based on where or how you are accessing Spark.

You can download the Iris.csv to test [here](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_irisdss/downloads/IRIS.csv/)

You can download Spark-Notebook [here](https://github.com/spark-notebook/spark-notebook)

It is a great tool, which will easily allow you to run a standalone spark cluster. If you want help with it on linux or Mac, I can provide instructions. Once you download it you need to use SBT to compile it... Use the following commands from the base directory `sbt`, then `run`

It will be accessible at localhost:9000

Required Imports

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeans
```

Method to create sqlContext in Spark-Notebook

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Defining Import Schema

```scala
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
StructField("c0", IntegerType, true),
StructField("Sepal_Length", DoubleType, true),
StructField("Sepal_Width", DoubleType, true),
StructField("Petal_Length", DoubleType, true),
StructField("Petal_Width", DoubleType, true),
StructField("Species", StringType, true)))
```

Making the DF

```scala
val iris_df = sqlContext.read
.format("csv")
.option("header", "true") //reading the headers
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
.schema(customSchema)
.load("/your/path/to/iris.csv")
```

Specifying features

```scala
val assembler = new 
VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("c0","Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width","Petal_Length","Petal_Width")).setOutputCol("features")
val iris_df_trans = assembler.transform(iris_df)
```

Model with 3 Clusters (change with .setK)

```scala
val bkm = new BisectingKMeans().setK(3).setSeed(1L).setFeaturesCol("features")
val model = bkm.fit(iris_df_trans)
```

Computing cost

```scala
val cost = model.computeCost(iris_df_trans)
```

Calculating Centers

```scala
println(s"Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = $cost")
println("Cluster Centers: ")
val centers = model.clusterCenters
centers.foreach(println)
```

### An Agglomerative Approach

The following provides an Agglomerative hierarchical clustering implementation in Spark which is worth a look, it is not included in the base MLlib like the bisecting Kmeans method and I do not have an example. But it is worth a look for those curious.

[Github Project](https://github.com/xiaocai00/SparkPinkMST)

[Youtube of Presentation at Spark-Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrfD431KLwc)

[Slides from Spark-Summit](https://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/a-scalable-hierarchical-clustering-algorithm-using-spark-spark-summit-east-talk-by-chen-jin)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Does it automatically apply the optimal number of clusters?
And how do you choose the seed in `setSeed()`?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I was able to find is divisive hierarchical clustering implemented in Spark ML via bisecting k-means (here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#bisecting-k-means)
I am planning to give it a try.

Have you found/tried anything?