# Similarity Matrix / Hierarchical agglomerative clustering spark

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib, hierarchical-clustering, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to implement a clustering method based on a similarity threshold. The idea is to define a threshold for what is considered similar and get the different clusters. The data I have contains 300 millions of entries. I have been having a look to *Apache Spark* for doing this. However, after a couple of hours I have more questions than answers:

1- All the methods *kmeans* (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html) implemented in Spark are basic on the similarity of Vectors making difficult to extend for other types of objects. In my case, I have a set of objects and I would like to extend the method that defined how two independent objects are similar, in the same way, we extend the function compare in Java to do comparisons. Is that possible? Can anyone provide an example? In all the examples I have seen are basic on vectors or sentences that are converted to vectors using *Word2Vector*.

2- All the methods of clustering in Spark you need to know the number of clusters *K* in advance. Does anyone know an implementation of Hierarchical Clustering that works in Spark.

Best Regards and thanks in advance.

BTW: I have check that many people are interested in this topic in StackOverflow, but nobody has produced a complete response.

Answer (score 1):

Pairwise operations *in general* do not scale - that is what you are describing here.  A 300M x 300M similarity matrix required 3*10^8 * (3*10^8-1)/2 operations - or `o(10^17)`.

You will need to break the data down into small pieces so that the pairwise comparisons happen among small groups.  The trick is - how to ensure that similar entries end up in the *same* small groups?  There are different ways to achieve this: one is simply to have a hierarchy of clusters.  One of them that is already built in to spark is `divisive bisecting kmeans`:  [Hierarchical Agglomerative clustering in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152337/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering-in-spark)

Another approach that is *not* built in to spark: For a set of new records you find the closest centroid at each level of clustering- and then at the leaf level *only* do a pairwise comparison among the cluster members.  This approach requires finding good repreentative cluster centroids/archetypes at each level